# Binary erosion query

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I looked at this link: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)#Grayscale_erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29#Grayscale_erosion)

I can understand that when you look at a pixel, with that structuring element, all pixel values around the origin need to be 1 in order for the pixel in question to be 1.

However, how would this binary erosion work if my structuring element was:

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

To rephrase the question. Would every pixel that lies on the cross need to be 1 in order for the origin pixel in question to be 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, yes. If **all** of the pixels in the structuring element that are **1** are touching object pixels, the output of the filter at the centre of the mask is 1.  If **any** pixel that is 1 in the mask is **not touching an object** (a.k.a. they're touching a pixel that is 0), the output of the filter at the centre of the mask is zero.

As an example, suppose your structuring element was like you stated

```
0 1 0 
1 1 1
0 1 0
```

Let's say our image looks like this:

```
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Let's assume for the moment we need to contain our structuring element within the image.  As such, we have **four** sliding neighbourhoods we need to consider.  As such, if we use our structuring element and slide from left to right, the output of the filter will affect the second row and the second, third, fourth and fifth columns.  We will ignore the borders and assume they're all zero.

The output of the filter at row 2, column 2 will be **1** as every pixel in the structuring element touches an object pixel.  If you slide over to the next window, the structuring element has elements in the mask that are **not** touching object pixels.  Specifically the north and south point, so the output is 0.  Sliding over to the right again, the north and east points have pixels that are not touching object pixels as dictated by the mask, and so the output is zero again.  Finally, the fifth column has points that are not touching pixels in the north, the middle and the south of the structuring element, and the output is zero yet again.  As such, the output should be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Make sense?

Comment: You just simplified a one hour lecture to a minute, thanks. On a side note, would binary dilation work just like this except instead of **all** of the pixels in the structuring element that are 1 are touching object pixels, **at least one** of the pixels in the structuring element that are 1 are touching object pixels?

Comment: @Clay: You got it buddy.  If **at least** one pixel in the mask is touching an object, the output at the centre of the filter is 1.  It's simply the reverse :)

Comment: @Clay: I used to teach image processing back when I was a part-time instructor at my university.  I eat and breathe this stuff for a living.  Hit me up if you have anymore questions, either with another comment or posting another question.  I'll be sure to answer you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I most likely will because I have an exam for image processing and computer graphics coming up :D